# Sub Domain Name Creation in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have an application on SAAS basis where I will be adding clients from backend or the clients can even create their own panel by signing up

While signing up or adding the client , the client or I will be assigning the sub domain . So suppose I am assigning subdomain xyz to client1 . Then the access url will be

xyz.maindomain.com

Now , I want .htaccess code in such a way that if xyz.maindomain.com is called, the url called must be maindomain.com?client=xyz .

Please guide me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to achieve what you wanted. No server-side scripting such as PHP required.

Say, put this in .htaccess file on your root www directory (or any relevant Apache *.conf file if you wish)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/?client=%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect `foo.example.com` to `http://www.example.com/?client=foo`

(change example.com to your domain name)

More about mod rewrite, with examples:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708

Hope this help.